# python, numba: adding a function reference to a typed list

Tags: python, list, function, numba

I am trying to build a list of functions that can be used inside jitted numba code. Since reflected lists are deprecated, I use numba's typed lists.  Appending to the typed list works as long as I keep adding the same function. However, adding a second function will fail. Is there a way to achieve this with numba?

```py
from numba.typed import List
from numba import njit
@njit()
def foo(b):
    b = b * 2.0
    return b

@njit()
def bar(a):
    a = a + 1.0
    return a

l = List()
l.append(foo) # this works
l.append(foo) # this will also work
l.append(bar) # this will fail
```

the full error message is here [https://pastebin.com/pBciXhGL][1]

Comment: https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/reference/pysupported.html#typed-list describes this as " type-homogeneous list", so I guess that is the reason you are not able to add `bar` to `l`, may I ask why you would like to add the functions to a list?

Comment: `foo` is of type `type(CPUDispatcher(<function foo at 0x00000200DB6AF040>))` and `bar` is of type `type(CPUDispatcher(<function bar at 0x00000200DBB964C0>))` as `List` must have homogeneous types you are not able to add `bar`. This should answer the "why" part

Comment: I thought being of type `CPUDispatcher` would be enough... as for the why. I have legacy OO-code where each object defines how it changes for a given times-step. Porting this to numba, either requires writing custom numba classes of each of the OO-classes of my project, or exposing the repective call methods as a function. I can now use regular python to loop over each obbject and call the respected jitted function, or I can assemble a list of functions I can use inside a numba optimized loop which would be much faster (this is only the inner loop, so it does matter)

Answer (score 0):

this solution works at least with the trivial case above

https://numba.discourse.group/t/typed-list-of-jitted-functions-in-jitclass/413/4